# Trying to center 4 lines of string in assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86-16, centering, bios, dosbox

So I'm new in Assembly Language and I'm trying to center 4 strings. But I don't know why it won't work.

These are the 4 strings I'm using in the code. When I'm running the program, *str1* is the only one that goes to the center. The rest is on the left.

```
str1 db "ADRIAN PAUL", 0AH, 0DH, "$"
str2 db "BS Computer Science", 0AH, 0DH, "$"
str3 db "09462524725", 0AH, 0DH, "$"
str4 db "macatopaul@gmail.com", 0AH, 0DH, "$"
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
 MOV AX, @DATA
 MOV DS, AX
 
 MOV AX, 0600H
 MOV BH, 07H
 MOV CX, 0000H ;CLEAR SCREEN
 MOV DX, 184FH
 INT 10H
 
 MOV AX, 0600h
 MOV BH, 07h
 MOV CX, 0000h
 MOV DX, 184Fh
 INT 10h
 
 MOV AH, 02h
 MOV BH, 00h
 MOV DH, 0Ch
 MOV DL, 24h
 INT 10h

MOV AH,09h
MOV DX, OFFSET str1
INT 21h
MOV CX,001Ah
MOV AH, 02h
INT 21h

MOV AH,09h
MOV DX, OFFSET str2
INT 21h
MOV CX,001Ah
MOV AH, 02h
INT 21h

MOV AH,09h
MOV DX, OFFSET str3
INT 21h
MOV CX,001Ah
MOV AH, 02h
INT 21h

MOV AH,09h
MOV DX, OFFSET str4
INT 21h
MOV CX,001Ah
MOV AH, 02h
INT 21h
```

Comment: Guessing what uncommented assembly code is doing is hard, even for an experienced programmer. Please add comments comments on the individual steps on what you think they should do.

Comment: If you don't want the cursor to move back to the first column of the screen, then you probably shouldn't be using Carriage Return characters (0Dh).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> MOV CX,001Ah
> MOV AH, 02h
> INT 21h
> ```

These lines invoke the **DOS** api function 02h that can display the character whose ASCII code is in the `DL` register. You did not use `DL`, so results will be unexpected.
Maybe you were trying to position the cursor with the **BIOS** api function 02h. That would make sense given your task description.

---

Best position the cursor right before outputting each string. And don't include the carriage return (13) and linefeed (10) in your strings because they make no sense anymore.

```
str1 db "ADRIAN PAUL$"
str2 db "BS Computer Science$"
str3 db "09462524725$"
str4 db "macatopaul@gmail.com$"
```

```
mov  bh, 0       ; DisplayPage
mov  dx, 0B23h   ; At(35,11)
mov  ah, 02h     ; BIOS.SetCursor
int  10h
mov  dx, OFFSET str1
mov  ah, 09h     ; DOS.PrintString
int  21h

mov  dx, 0C1Eh   ; At(30,12)
mov  ah, 02h     ; BIOS.SetCursor
int  10h
mov  dx, OFFSET str2
mov  ah, 09h     ; DOS.PrintString
int  21h

mov  dx, 0D23h   ; At(35,13)
mov  ah, 02h     ; BIOS.SetCursor
int  10h
mov  dx, OFFSET str3
mov  ah, 09h     ; DOS.PrintString
int  21h

mov  dx, 0E1Eh   ; At(30,14)
mov  ah, 02h     ; BIOS.SetCursor
int  10h
mov  dx, OFFSET str4
mov  ah, 09h     ; DOS.PrintString
int  21h
```

Expected output in the center of the 80x25 text screen:

> ```
>                                    ADRIAN PAUL
>                               BS Computer Science  
>                                    09462524725  
>                               macatopaul@gmail.com
> ```